# Zenity --auto-kill is not working on a ghostscript process

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, kill, zenity

I'm with a problem with the `--auto-kill` zenity option, which function is, according to `zenity --help-progress`, used to kill parent process if Cancel button is pressed. That's what I need in this line:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$FOLDER.pdf" "$FILE" | zenity --progress --title="Processing" --auto-kill --time-remaining --auto-close  --width=220 --text="Creating PDF" --pulsate --percentage=0
```

But for some reason, when I end it clicking on the Cancel button, the gs command continues running and creating the PDF file, even though the terminal is "free to use" again.

The script stops, nothing past this line runs, only the gs keeps running until the pdf is created.

How can I fix it? Am I misunderstanding the `--auto-kill` option? Thanks.